# Tomcat - associate thread to session

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Is it possible to determine which session is active on a particular thread in Tomcat?

I'm investigating an issue with 100% CPU utilization at random times.  Using PSI Probe (and VisualVM) I've identified two ajp threads that appear deadlocked in `HashMap.getEntry()`.  This will give me the stack trace, but I'd really like to find out which session, and, if possible, URL, initiated the request.

Answer (score 0):

A "session" in terms of "HttpSession" likely isn't consuming any resources.  Most likely you meant "request" not "session".

If that's the case you can add System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() );

If that compared to the access logs, it should be relatively straightforward to find the URL to Thread correspondance.

Comment: No, I mean session (jsessionid), not request.  PSI Probe and Tomcat manager both list these sessions by application, along with client IP and timings.  This is what I want to get at.  And I am using a third-party application so adding code to print the thread name is not possible for me.  I did find that PSI Probe does show URLs for active threads, so that gets me halfway there.